# Wpf forcing a MenuItem to create it's Children

Tags: wpf, binding, menuitem

I have a c# wpf question. 
I am binding a MenuItem  to  list that is dynamic. Every object on the list is a new sub MenuItem to the main one.

All the items are Checkable and implement the events of checked and unchecked.
The problem is that even before the first opening of the main MenuItem by the user I want the checked and unchecked events to appear (they seem to apear only the first time the user opens the main MenuItem even though add items are added to the binded list before that).

I can do it manually (even though It looks horrible) but when the main MenuItem opens up for the first time the events are called also, and it creates a mess.

So basiclly I need a way to "force" the main MenuItem to create it's children when I tell it to so that the checked and unchecked events will work.

I have tried everything, and even UpdateLayout did not work. Even when I open the menu from the WindowLoaded evet I need to keep it open even after the end of the event and only than it creates the childrens (I thought I could open it and close it real fast so it will be unnoticed to the user).

I hope my question was clear enough.

I thank you in advance. :-)

Comment: I think you mean "before the first opening of the main MenuItem by the user I want the checked and unchecked events to execute".

Answer (score 1):

Since it is an event on the menu it kind of makes sense.  When you say manually what are you doing?  I would just create a helper and call it on load and by the event.  Create a private List Bool to store the status of the check and only run the real event code if the status changes.